# Managing Permissions of Project Members of a Google Cloud Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to change the permissions of a user within a Google Cloud Project (from Editor to Owner). This is not possible and I receive the following error message:

> Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try
>   again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back
>   later.

The problem does not seem to solve itself. Does anyone have any experience on how to overcome this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/sY5a_YLyNtA/lC7M2E6SEAAJ) which a similar issue has been posted. This problem should be resolved by now.